# Want help in testing my ios app on iphone

Tags: image, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

I have developed an iOS app in which i am using very large no of .png images for that i have created a SQLite database of the name of that images i took image name from that database and load image, i have added all the images into the Supporting Files folder of my projects,

when i run the program in simulator it runs perfectly but when i tested that same project on my iPhone 5 the program runs but the images could not seen the error said that could not find the file

My code to retrieve image is below

```
NSBundle *dataBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

**retriving image name from SQLite database**

```
NSString *imagename= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 6)];
```

**Loading the Image in my imageview**

```
NSString *imgPath = [dataBundle pathForResource:imagename ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
[self.showImg setImage:img];
```

This code works perfectly on iOS simulatore 5.1 & iOS simulatore 6.0 in both screen size but it did not work on iPhone 5

I think that the problem is that images are not copied in my iPhone, so can anybody has solution and how to attach this all images in my archive

Comment: Did you NSLog imgPath and see if the path is valid?

Answer (score 0):

when you run your project into simulator the image path is working fine because it takes path from your image source from your computer. when you try to run in your iPhone it takes image source path from your iPhone source.Check the image where are you added. if it added into your project then it's working fine with both simulator as well in iPhone. it you just given reference of image to project then only show in simulator. so please check your image folder.

Comment: I had copied the image folder in my project.

Comment: when you add the images have you tick the two check box button 1)Copy items into destination group's folder and 2)your project ?

Comment: Yes i did and after your answer i remove the the folder and added again with both the check box checked.

Comment: try remove your old one app from iPhone and then run again your project. also check the image path with NSLog

Comment: why you are taking this image path you can directly load this image with imagename only

Comment: I also had removed my app from iPhone not only one time but several times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21366/discussion-between-hi-ren-and-rudasagani)

Comment: No i could not understand it at all.